# How to show time in AM or PM format from TimeOfDay with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, time

I used `ShowTimePicker` class to select time according to my wish
but want to show it in PM or AM with `Text` .like 9:00 AM, 10:00 PM.

means take 12 hours format.

Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class ShowTimePickerDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowTimePickerDemoState createState() => _ShowTimePickerDemoState();
}

class _ShowTimePickerDemoState extends State<ShowTimePickerDemo> {
  TimeOfDay pickedTime = TimeOfDay.now();

  Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay response = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: pickedTime,
    );
    if (response != null && response != pickedTime) {
      setState(() {
        pickedTime = response;
      });
    }
  } 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(pickedTime.toString()),
            SizedBox(height:10),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: (){
                _selectTime(context);
              }, 
              child: Text("Show Time Pikcer")
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OutPut screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you have the time selected, you can format it with `new DateFormat.jm()`, which will output, for example, `5:00 PM`. See [DateFormat docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) for more.

Edit: You could do this a few ways.

One way is to use a function, like this:

```dart
String formatTimeOfDay(TimeOfDay tod) {
    final now = new DateTime.now();
    final dt = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, tod.hour, tod.minute);
    final format = DateFormat.jm();  //"6:00 AM"
    return format.format(dt);
}
```

Another way is to use this is in the example provided from the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html):

```dart
print(new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(new DateTime.now()));
```

Comment: Okay, so how do I write code? my selected time in  `pickedTime` variable , which type of `TimeOfDay`. so where i put into  `new DateFormat.jm()`.?

Answer (score 3):

When you have identified the `TimeOfDay` class of Flutter, you can now convert the used variable to change it's current format to 12-hour system.

```
TimeOfDay initialTime = TimeOfDay.now();

initialTime.format(context)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this method to get formatted Date

```
getformattedTime(TimeOfDay time) {
    return '${time.hour}:${time.minute} ${time.period.toString().split('.')[1]}';
  }
```

This returns the following value:
***10:39 am***

Answer (score 0):

There is a pre-define property inside TimeOfDay object called period that return DayPeriod either am or pm as per the selection.

```
onTimeButtonClick(BuildContext context) async {
    TimeOfDay? _timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    DayPeriod dayPeriod = _timeOfDay!.period;
    print(dayPeriod); // This will return => DayPeriod.am/DayPeriod.pm as per the selection of time.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var time = TimeOfDay(hour: 11, minute: 55).format(context);
 print(time);
```

It will result: 11:55 Am